# md-select showing multiple selections after updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-material

I created an [issue on the material github](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9981), but with their focus on material2, I wanted to get some help from the gurus on here to determine if this is something I'm doing or if it's a problem with angularjs/material.  So here's my issue:

[image]

The user can add a certification by selecting from the dropdown and clicking "ADD NEW".  Those certifications are bound to an `ng-repeat` which generates the cards in yellow.  Those cards have lists all bound to the same datatype.  As you can see above, I'm clicking on this icon to open a dialog which presents a form for adding an item to a list which populates the `md-select`s on the page.  After adding to the list, the `md-select`'s selected label shows two of the same items are selected.  `multiple` is not enabled on the `md-select`s and each selected id only has one value.  Clicking on the `md-side-nav`, tab title, or `md-select` itself will update the selected label to show properly.  Inspecting the DOM, there are no duplicate items.  I have [attempted to recreate this issue on codepen](http://codepen.io/astynax777/pen/eBYpNK) but so far I've been unsuccessful.  This is my layout:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab>
        <md-tab-label>
            Certifications
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
            <div layout="row" layout-padding>
                <div flex="50">
                    <md-input-container>
                        <label>Last Audit</label>
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="addEditSupplierCtrl.supplier.dateLastAudit"></md-datepicker>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <md-input-container>
                        <label>Next Audit</label>
                        <md-datepicker ng-model="addEditSupplierCtrl.supplier.dateNextAudit"></md-datepicker>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" layout-padding>
                <md-input-container style="min-width: 200px;">
                    <label>Certification Type</label>
                    <md-select ng-model="addEditSupplierCtrl.newSupplierCertification.certificationTypeId">
                        <md-option ng-repeat="certificationType in addEditSupplierCtrl.certificationTypes" value="{{ certificationType.id }}">
                            {{ certificationType.name }}
                        </md-option>
                    </md-select>
                </md-input-container>
                <div>
                    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="addEditSupplierCtrl.addSupplierCertification($event)">Add New</md-button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" layout-wrap>
                <md-card md-theme="{{ certification.requiresAudit ? 'audit' : 'default' }}" ng-repeat="certification in addEditSupplierCtrl.supplier.supplierCertifications | orderBy:'certificationType.name'" flex="100" flex-gt-sm="40" flex-gt-md="30">
                    <md-card-title flex="none">
                        <md-card-title-text>
                            <div style="position: relative">
                                <strong>Selected Id:</strong> {{ certification.certificationTypeId | json }}<br />
                                <md-input-container style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 350px;">
                                    <label>Certification Type</label>
                                    <md-select ng-model="certification.certificationTypeId">
                                        <md-option ng-repeat="certificationType in addEditSupplierCtrl.certificationTypes" value="{{ certificationType.id }}">
                                            {{ certificationType.name }}
                                        </md-option>
                                    </md-select>
                                </md-input-container>
                                <br /><strong>Select List Data:</strong> {{ addEditSupplierCtrl.certificationTypes | json }}
                                <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" ng-click="addEditSupplierCtrl.showAddCertificationTypeDialog($event)">
                                    <md-icon>playlist_add</md-icon>
                                </md-button>
                                <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0">
                                    <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" title="Delete Certification" ng-click="addEditSupplierCtrl.deleteCertification($event, certification)">
                                        <md-icon>cancel</md-icon>
                                    </md-button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </md-card-title-text>
                    </md-card-title>
                    <md-card-content>
                        <div class="md-media-sm card-media" flex>
                            <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="certification.requiresAudit">
                                Requires Audit
                            </md-checkbox>
                            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                                <label>Number</label>
                                <input ng-model="certification.number" />
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container>
                                <label>Expiration</label>
                                <md-datepicker ng-model="certification.expirationDate"></md-datepicker>
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container class="md-block">
                                <label>Notes</label>
                                <textarea ng-model="certification.notes"></textarea>
                            </md-input-container>
                        </div>
                    </md-card-content>
                </md-card>
            </div>
        </md-tab-body>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

and here's my logic:

```
(function () {
angular.module('ASLApp').controller('AddEditSupplierController', AddEditSupplierController);

function AddEditSupplierController(addMode, $scope, $routeParams, $mdDialog, RandomService, SupplierService, CertificationTypeService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.save = function (evt) {
        vm.loading = true;
        SupplierService.update(vm.supplier).then(function (response) {
            vm.supplier = response.data;
            parseDates();
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.data && response.data.Errors && response.data.Errors.length > 0 && response.data.Errors[0].number === 2627) {
                $mdDialog.show(
                  $mdDialog.alert()
                    .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                    .title('Duplicate Supplier Id Entry Found')
                    .textContent('Another supplier entry was found with the same Id.')
                    .ok('Ok')
                );
            }
        }).finally(function () {
            vm.loading = false;
        });
    };

    vm.addSupplierCertification = function (evt) {
        if (!vm.supplier.supplierCertifications) {
            vm.supplier.supplierCertifications = [];
        }
        vm.supplier.supplierCertifications.push(vm.newSupplierCertification);
        vm.newSupplierCertification = {
            certificationTypeId: vm.certificationTypes[0].id,
            tempId: RandomService.guid()
        };
    };

    vm.generateId = function (evt) {
        SupplierService.generateId(vm.supplier.name).then(function (response) {
            vm.supplier.id = response.data;
        });
    };

    vm.showAddCertificationTypeDialog = function (evt) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            scope: $scope,
            preserveScope: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/views/AddCertificationTypeDialog.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: evt
        });
    };

    vm.cancelDialog = function (evt) {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    vm.addCertificationType = function () {
        CertificationTypeService.add(vm.newCertificationType).then(function (response) {
            vm.newCertificationType = {};
            getCertificationTypes();
            $mdDialog.hide();
        });
    };

    function init() {
        vm.addMode = addMode;
        if (!addMode) {
            getSupplier($routeParams.id);
        }
        getCertificationTypes();
    }

    function getSupplier(id) {
        vm.loading = true;
        SupplierService.get(id).then(function (response) {
            vm.supplier = response.data;
            parseDates();
        }).finally(function () {
            vm.loading = false;
        });
    }

    function getCertificationTypes() {
        CertificationTypeService.getAll().then(function (response) {
            if (vm.certificationTypes)
                delete vm.certificationTypes;

            vm.certificationTypes = response.data;

            vm.newSupplierCertification = {
                certificationTypeId: vm.certificationTypes[0].id,
                tempId: RandomService.guid()
            };
        });
    }

    function parseDates() {
        if (vm.supplier.dateLastReview) {
            vm.supplier.dateLastReview = new Date(vm.supplier.dateLastReview);
        }

        if (vm.supplier.dateNextReview) {
            vm.supplier.dateNextReview = new Date(vm.supplier.dateNextReview);
        }

        if (vm.supplier.dateLastAudit) {
            vm.supplier.dateLastAudit = new Date(vm.supplier.dateLastAudit);
        }

        if (vm.supplier.dateNextAudit) {
            vm.supplier.dateNextAudit = new Date(vm.supplier.dateNextAudit);
        }

        if (vm.supplier.supplierCertifications) {
            angular.forEach(vm.supplier.supplierCertifications, function (certification) {
                if (certification.expirationDate) {
                    certification.expirationDate = new Date(certification.expirationDate);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    init();
}

AddEditSupplierController.$inject = ['addMode', '$scope', '$routeParams', '$mdDialog', 'RandomService', 'SupplierService', 'CertificationTypeService'];
}());
```

At one point during my troubleshooting, I removed the other tabs and after adding a new item to the list, it showed the multiple selections for a half second, but then it updated to show properly.  This makes me wonder if there is some sort of `debounce` happening.  Being able to reproduce this on my codepen would be extremely helpful in narrowing down the issue which I suspect to be related to timing of events.  Any assistance would be appreciated!

Troubleshooting update:
I tried adding a `$timeout` call to my `getCertificationTypes` method with no results, so I doubled the call to `getCertificationTypes`.  It added another duplicate to the selected value label.

```
    vm.addCertificationType = function () {
        CertificationTypeService.add(vm.newCertificationType).then(function (response) {
            vm.newCertificationType = {};
            $timeout(getCertificationTypes, 1000);
            $timeout(getCertificationTypes, 1000);
            //getCertificationTypes();
            $mdDialog.hide();
        });
    };
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code that you have in `showAddCertificationTypeDialog` for the template? I think the problem is there

Comment: I updated your code pen. Look at $mdDialog for adding `certificationType` and try to implemented like its implemented in the codepen. I think that will solve your problem. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqbWdd

Comment: So that I understand your thinking and the change you made, you're suggesting that I create an anonymous controller in the `$mdDialog` and pass a return value back to the original controller?

Comment: Yes. I think you have reference problem. If you isolate the $scope from the modal i think your problem will be solwed

Comment: Done.  Sorry mate.  No change.

Comment: Hm. Try wrapping in `$scope.$apply` adding the new certidicationTypes you get from server in `getCertificationTypes()`  function

Comment: I thought about that too but figured it wouldn't work because it was probably already in a digest cycle and would likely throw an error.  I was hoping to find a way to trigger an additional digest after this `getCertificationTypes` digest, but don't know if that's possible.  Perhaps with a `$timeout`.

Comment: Yea try in `$timeout` with 0 as debounce. Just to skip one event loop

Comment: See my edit above...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127821/discussion-between-kliment-and-zach).

Comment: I see the problem is when you switch the source data in the md-select. So try this. When you add new certificationType instead of fetching again from the server, just save it to the server and if you get success response don't refresh the certificationTypes array, just append the created certificationType to the existing one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments and in the chat, the problem is with the `md-select` when the reference of the array that prints `md-option` changes the model is not updated and there is anomaly in the preview of `md-select` as you can see in the question. That's because `ng-repeat` rerenders all of the `md-option` and there is bug in angular material that doesn't handle this use case properly.

The solution is to add `track by` property in the `ng-repeat` so the whole list is not rerendered

```
<md-select ng-model="certification.certificationTypeId">
    <md-option ng-repeat="certificationType in addEditSupplierCtrl.certificationTypes track by certificationType.id" value="{{ certificationType.id }}">
           {{ certificationType.name }}
     </md-option>
</md-select>
```